# In WinUI-3 Facing issue (Showing error "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Catastrophic failure (0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))'")

Tags: c#, xaml, winapi, winui-3

I am working on winUi3 project. When I am trying to add item in ComboBox That time facing this issue.

I have a ComboBox and it's editable, when I am entering value in that ComboBox input panel I want to display on List of ComboBox but facing some problem there.

**This is code of my xaml file.**

---

```xml
<ComboBox 
    IsEditable="True"
    x:Name="userList"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind UserViewModel.Users,Mode=TwoWay}"
    KeyUp="AddUsers"
    SelectedValue="{x:Bind SelectedValue,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

---

**This is Code Behind File xaml.cs**

---

```cs
private void AddUsers(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input.KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Enter)
        {
            ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
            string enteredValue = cmb.Text;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(enteredValue))
            {
                userList.Items.Add(enteredValue); // In this Line exception occurring
                userList.Text = string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
```

---

I am doing Like this but I am facing issue that time a error is occurring that is,

*"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Catastrophic failure (0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))'"*
[This is error] https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUeLG.png

Comment: Be aware that WinUI is neither WPF nor WinForms. The most similar other framework is UWP.

Comment: You should change the bound items source, which seems to be `UserViewModel.Users` here (and this source should probably be an ObservableCollection of User)  or post a reproducible sample code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The document, *Combo box and list box*, has a [Sample - Validate input and use locally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/combo-box#sample---validate-input-and-add-to-list) which also shows adding items to the binding source. @Mahesh

Answer (score 1):

You need to add items to the binding source:

```cs
private void AddUsers(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Enter)
    {
        ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
        string enteredValue = cmb.Text;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(enteredValue))
        {
            UserViewModel.Users.Add(enteredValue);
            userList.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```